spdlog an Qt - app crashes after sending a string to the logger
I like to use spdlog for a small app. It crashes every time i send a message to the logger.
Wrote a small test scenario:
//***main.cpp***
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "logger.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    std::cout << "start test\n";
    init();
    auto logger = spdlog::get("GUI"); 
    std::cout<< "got logger"; //until here everything fine
    logger->info("test123"); **//here it crashes**
    std::cout << "finish test\n";
    spdlog::shutdown();

    return a.exec();
}

//***logger.h***
#include "spdlog/async.h"
#include "spdlog/spdlog.h"
#include "spdlog/sinks/rotating_file_sink.h"

void init();
constexpr auto max_file_size = 1024+1024*5;
constexpr auto max_files = 5;
constexpr auto filename = "logs/logs.txt";

//**logger.cpp**
#include "Logger.h"
#include <QDir>
#include <iostream>

void init()
{
    try
    {
        auto sharedFileSink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::rotating_file_sink_mt>(filename, max_file_size, max_files, false);

        ///GUI Logger
        auto guilogger = std::make_shared<spdlog::logger>("GUI", sharedFileSink);
        spdlog::register_logger(guilogger);
        spdlog::set_default_logger(spdlog::get("GUI"));
        spdlog::get("GUI")->info("Selftest after register OK");//no problem here
    }
    catch (const spdlog::spdlog_ex& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "Log initialization failed: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}

It seems ist crashes every time i send a string to the logger in the main.cpp.
But I can see the logs that are used in the init function.
Does anyone have an idea?

Cannot reproduce, for me works fine, logs to file, doesn't crash, and I didn't detect any memory violations. When you run it with debugger, where exactly is the crash and what is the reason?

What does your debugger tell you?

It says "segmentation fault"
jmp    0x7fff830dccb3 <ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+67>
in the disassembler.
Probably while thying to create a new thread?
